# How do i loop proxies with each request

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, networking, proxy

Hi i want to code a request spammer that requests a page on a site repeatedly with a different proxy.

I have been troubleshooting with wireshark if my requests are going through or not.

this is my code:

```
import requests
from itertools import cycle
import traceback

#def get_proxies():
    url = 'https://free-proxy-list.net/'
    response = requests.get(url)
    parser = fromstring(response.text)
    proxies = set()
    for i in parser.xpath('//tbody/tr')[:10]:
        if i.xpath('.//td[7][contains(text(),"yes")]'):
            proxy = ":".join([i.xpath('.//td[1]/text()')[0], i.xpath('.//td[2]/text()')[0]])
            proxies.add(proxy)
    return proxies

proxies = open('proxies.txt', 'r')


#proxies = get_proxies()
#proxy_pool = cycle(proxies)
url = "https://www.bol.com/nl"

print(''' Request spammer V1.0''')

print("\n\n TARGET URL: " + url)

for i in range(1,3892):
    #Get a proxy from the pool
    #proxy = next(proxy_pool)
    proxy = proxies.readline()
    print("Request: #%d "%i +" "+ proxy)
    try:
        response = requests.get(url,proxies={"http": proxy, "https": proxy})
    except:
        #Most free proxies will often get connection errors. You will have retry the entire request using another proxy to work. 
        #We will just skip retries as its beyond the scope of this tutorial and we are only downloading a single url 
        print("Skipping. Connnection error")
```

But what's really happening is that whenever it says Connection Error it will include the proxy ip as i coded here: `print("Request: #%d "%i +" "+ proxy)` but when it doesn't it will only print "Request #1,2,3 etc.."

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think what you are doing is the best idea. I mean, spamming? Sounds like DDos.

Comment: I have permission to do this for my partner and he agreed with the idea, i'm not intending to cause server issues or black hat activities

Comment: Got it :) Good luck!